# Intercept the menu click

Tags: android, button

how could i intercept the click on the menu button of the device (phone for example).
I need something like `OnMenuClick()`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solve it my self, like this

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)  {

    if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU||keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && event.getRepeatCount() == 0) {

        // my code here...        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You  need to implement 2 things.

1. onCreateOptionsMenu()
2. onOptionMenuItemClick().

All click events will come to 2.

[Sample is here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html).

Comment: Modified the answer. Kindly check

Answer (score 0):

You can to handle when the menu is opened with *onMenuOpened()*

Comment: i tryied this but nothing happened
  ' @Override
        public boolean onMenuOpened(int featureId, Menu menu) {
         TextView text= (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textView1);
         text.setText("Tu as cliquer sur le button menu ");
         
   return false;
        
    }'

Comment: onMenuOpened() is called when a panel's menu is opened by the user. The panel's menu is opened when you click on Menu button, but also it is opened in other cases. I don't know if it is what you looking for

Answer (score 0):

implement

> onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu)

it gets called every time the menu button is clicked